# n-duple recursion, Python, through exec() function

Tags: python, recursion

I coded this program:

```
def f1():
    print("1")
    f2()
  
def f2():
    print("2")
    f3()

def f3():
    print("3")
    f4()
  
def f4():
    print("4")
    f1()


f1()
```

It works. Now I intend to code the same but containing n functions in one cycle. Here is my attempt:

```
n=4

s=""

for i in range(n-1):
    s+="""
    def f{}():
        print("{}")
        f{}()
        
    """.format(i+1,i+1,i+2)



s+="""
def f{}():
    print("{}")
    f{}()
""".format(n,n,1)

#print(s) #only for testing

exec(s)
f1()
```

Can I ask what is wrong? Here is the compiler output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 23, in <module>
File "<string>", line 2
    def f1():
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>
```

More info: In the second code the attempt is to save the content of n functions into a string and then use exec() function to convert it into an executable code.

Thank you.

Comment: In the `for` loop the text in the `"""` quotes needs to be shifted left. At least the `def f{}():` part so that it is at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Thank you. You are right! Looking for the reason, I cannot find any. Additional spaces should not be a problem in a multiline string... also it is inside the for cycle so there should be the indent..

Comment: If you `print(s)` you will see the first `def...` lines will have different indentation levels than the last one.

Comment: "Additional spaces should not be a problem in a multiline string" - I can't understand why you thought so. The string *is code that you intended to execute*, right? Could you put those spaces in the source code file? No? So....

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on Johnny Mopp's comment:

```
n=7

s=""

for i in range(n-1):
    s+="""
def f{}():
    print("{}")
    f{}()
    """.format(i+1,i+1,i+2)



s+="""
def f{}():
    print("{}")
    f{}()
""".format(n,n,1)

#print(s)

exec(s)
f1()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).